Failed to fetch Music Recommendation. Status Code: 404
I am trying to build a system that curates music based on emotions or that is the idea for now, it was working perfectly fine for a while but suddenly whenever I want to retrieve recommendations based on emotions, I am getting a 404 status code error. I am really not able to pinpoint the problem
I'll share a few codes which is like the core concept, If I could get to know the exact solution to the problem or where the problem lies it would be helpful
Music.py
import requests
import random
from ai_ml.src.utils import get_spotify_access_token
from ai_ml.src.config import CONFIG

def get_music_recommendation(emotion, market=None):
    try:
        access_token = get_spotify_access_token()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error retrieving access token: {e}")
        return []

    emotion_to_genre = {
    "happy": [
        "acoustic", "afrobeat", "alt-rock", "alternative", "ambient", "blues", 
        "bossa nova", "brazil", "chill", "classical", "club", "comedy", "dance", 
        "disco", "drum-and-bass", "edm", "electro", "electronic", "folk", "funk", 
        "garage", "gospel", "groove", "grunge", "happy", "house", "idm", "indie", 
        "indie-pop", "industrial", "j-dance", "j-idol", "j-pop", "j-rock", "jazz", 
        "k-pop", "kids", "latin", "latino", "pop", "pop-film", "post-dubstep", 
        "power-pop", "progressive-house", "reggae", "reggaeton", "rock", "rock-n-roll", 
        "salsa", "samba", "show-tunes", "singer-songwriter", "ska", "summer", 
        "swedish", "synth-pop", "tango", "techno", "trance", "world-music"
    ],
    "sad": [
        "blues", "classical", "emo", "folk", "indie-pop", "jazz", "latin", "latino", 
        "metalcore", "post-dubstep", "punk", "r-n-b", "rainy-day", "rock", "sad", 
        "singer-songwriter", "soul"
    ],
    "angry": [
        "black-metal", "death-metal", "grindcore", "hardcore", "heavy-metal", 
        "industrial", "metal", "metal-misc", "metalcore", "punk-rock", "punk"
    ],
    "surprise": [
        "anime", "electro", "experimental", "idm", "j-dance", "j-idol", "j-pop", 
        "j-rock", "post-dubstep", "psych-rock", "trip-hop", "turkish"
    ],
    "neutral": [
        "acoustic", "ambient", "chill", "classical", "country", "dancehall", "deep-house", 
        "detroit-techno", "dub", "dubstep", "edm", "electro", "electronic", "folk", 
        "french", "groove", "hard-rock", "honky-tonk", "house", "idm", "indie", 
        "indie-pop", "industrial", "j-pop", "kids", "latin", "mpb", "new-age", 
        "new-release", "opera", "party", "pop", "reggae", "reggaeton", "rockabilly", 
        "singer-songwriter", "soul", "soundtracks", "study", "synth-pop", "techno"
    ]
}


    genre = emotion_to_genre.get(emotion.lower(), "pop")

    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
    }

    available_markets = [
        "AD", "AE", "AG", "AL", "AM", "AO", "AR", "AT", "AU", "AZ", "BA", "BB", "BD", "BE", "BF", "BG", "BH", "BI",
        "BJ", "BN", "BO", "BR", "BS", "BT", "BW", "BY", "BZ", "CA", "CD", "CG", "CH", "CI", "CL", "CM", "CO", "CR",
        "CV", "CW", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DJ", "DK", "DM", "DO", "DZ", "EC", "EE", "EG", "ES", "ET", "FI", "FJ", "FM",
        "FR", "GA", "GB", "GD", "GE", "GH", "GM", "GN", "GQ", "GR", "GT", "GW", "GY", "HK", "HN", "HR", "HT", "HU",
        "ID", "IE", "IL", "IN", "IQ", "IS", "IT", "JM", "JO", "JP", "KE", "KG", "KH", "KI", "KM", "KN", "KR", "KW",
        "KZ", "LA", "LB", "LC", "LI", "LK", "LR", "LS", "LT", "LU", "LV", "LY", "MA", "MC", "MD", "ME", "MG", "MH",
        "MK", "ML", "MN", "MO", "MR", "MT", "MU", "MV", "MW", "MX", "MY", "MZ", "NA", "NE", "NG", "NI", "NL", "NO",
        "NP", "NR", "NZ", "OM", "PA", "PE", "PG", "PH", "PK", "PL", "PR", "PS", "PT", "PW", "PY", "QA", "RO", "RS",
        "RW", "SA", "SB", "SC", "SE", "SG", "SI", "SK", "SL", "SM", "SN", "SR", "ST", "SV", "SZ", "TD", "TG", "TH",
        "TJ", "TL", "TN", "TO", "TR", "TT", "TV", "TW", "TZ", "UA", "UG", "US", "UY", "UZ", "VC", "VE", "VN", "VU",
        "WS", "XK", "ZA", "ZM", "ZW"
    ]

    selected_market = market if market in available_markets else random.choice(available_markets)


    params = {
        "seed_genres": genre,
        "limit": 25,
        "market": selected_market
    }

    if emotion == "happy":
        params["target_valence"] = 0.8
        params["target_energy"] = 0.7
    elif emotion == "sad":
        params["target_valence"] = 0.2
        params["target_energy"] = 0.2
    elif emotion == "angry":
        params["target_valence"] = 0.2
        params["target_energy"] = 0.9
    elif emotion == "surprise":
        params["target_valence"] = 0.6
        params["target_energy"] = 0.8
    else:
        params["target_valence"] = 0.5
        params["target_energy"] = 0.5

    response = requests.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/recommendations", headers=headers, params=params)

    if response.status_code == 401:
        print("Access token expired. Please refresh the token.")
        return []
    elif response.status_code != 200:
        print(f"Failed to fetch music recommendations. Status code: {response.status_code}")
        return []

    tracks = response.json().get("tracks", [])
    recommended_tracks = [
        {
            "name": track["name"],
            "artist": ", ".join([artist["name"] for artist in track["artists"]]),
            "preview_url": track.get("preview_url"),
            "external_url": track.get("external_urls", {}).get("spotify"),
            "image_url": next((img["url"] for img in track["album"]["images"]), None),
            "album_name": track["album"]["name"],
            "release_date": track["album"].get("release_date"),
            "track_duration": track.get("duration_ms") // 1000 if track.get("duration_ms") else None,
            "popularity": track.get("popularity"),
            "explicit": track.get("explicit"),  
        }
        for track in tracks
    ]

    if not recommended_tracks:
        print(f"No tracks found for genre: {genre}")

    return recommended_tracks`

utils.py
import base64
import requests
from ai_ml.src.config import CONFIG

def get_spotify_access_token():
    client_id = CONFIG["spotify_client_id"]
    client_secret = CONFIG["spotify_client_secret"]
    token_url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"

    # Create the authorization header
    auth_header = base64.b64encode(f"{client_id}:{client_secret}".encode()).decode()

    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Basic {auth_header}"
    }

    data = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials"
    }

    response = requests.post(token_url, headers=headers, data=data)

    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception("Failed to retrieve Spotify access token")

    return response.json().get("access_token")

config is a separate python script with my client and client_secret id

Seems that recommendations endpoint was deprecated as of 2024-11-27. may be it's definition changed too.

As @LMC correctly points out, recommendations is deprecated. Furthermore, you were omitting some Required parameters. Please review Spotify's API documentation. This is not a Python issue per se

Thank you @LMC for the quick responses. It was a silly question and  pointed out the problem, the recommendations endpoint was indeed depreciated. Thank you very much for the help

Thank you @SIGHUP for the quick responses.  Thank you very much for the help and pointing me in the right direction. The recommendations endpoint was depreciated so will be using search endpoint from now on. Thank you again
